# Search for many things in a json file

Tags: python, pandas

I am having issue creating a dictionary list by searching for many strings. From a json document I would like to extract the type of cat and snail and export these findings into a separate file. I am able to do it for one feature, that being cat. However I am having issues with doing it with more than 1 feature. Or even look to do it in an efficient way.

Sample Data

```
"type": "blah",
"animals": [
    {
        "type": "dog1",
        "name": "oscar",
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "dog2",
        "name": "John",
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "snail1",
        "name": "Fred",
        "Colors": [
            "Red"
        ],
        "Contact_info": [
            {
                "Owner": "Jill",
                "Owner_number": "123"
            }
        ],
    
    },
    {
        "type": "cat3",
        "name": "Freddy",
        "Colors": [
            "Blue"
        ],
        "Contact_info": [
            {
                "Owner": "Ann",
                "Owner_number": "1323"
            }
        ],
```

Idea Result

```
{
    "type": "snail1",
    "name": "Fred",
    "Colors": [
        "Red"
    ],
    "Contact_info": [
        {
            "Owner": "Jill",
            "Owner_number": "123"
        }
    ],

},
{
    "type": "cat3",
    "name": "Freddy",
    "Colors": [
        "Blue"
    ],
    "Contact_info": [
        {
            "Owner": "Ann",
            "Owner_number": "1323"
        }
    ],
```

Code so far:

```
with open("data.json", "rb") as f:
    # Load obj list
    data = json.load(f)["animals"]

# Create a list of dictionaries if obj type contains "snail" or cat
animal= [a for a in data if "snail" in a.get("type")]
animal = [a for a in data if "cat" in a.get("type")]
```

Comment: How is this question related to pandas?

Comment: Please post a valid format for your sample data.

Comment: Hey mate, your data format was incorrect or half-provided which is not a sample and may vex people trying to help you. It is highly recommended for you to check all the information you are providing before publishing it. This will make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code written is partially correct, however, the error comes up where you have similar variables in the last 2 lines. In the snail part, you are creating a variable and then in the cat one you are again redefining that variable *(this totally erases the value of the animal variable defined above)*. For example

```
var = 'Hi'
var = 'Bye'
print(var) #Output: Bye
```

Hence, you should either use different variables or totally use another method

```
animals_required = ["cat", "snail"]
animal_list = [i for i in data["animals"] for animal in animals_required if animal in i["type"]]
#List Comprehension
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it:

```
# Only Cats:
cats = [animal for animal in data.get("animals") if "cat" in animal.get("type")]

# Only Snails:
snails = [animal for animal in data.get("animals") if "snail" in animal.get("type")]

# Both Cats and Snails
cats_n_snails = [
    animal
    for animal in data.get("animals")
    if "cat" in animal.get("type") or "snail" in animal.get("type")
]
```

Provided that this is the data:

```
data = {
   "type":"blah",
   "animals":[
      {
         "type":"dog1",
         "name":"oscar"
      },
      {
         "type":"dog2",
         "name":"John"
      },
      {
         "type":"snail1",
         "name":"Fred",
         "Colors":[
            "Red"
         ],
         "Contact_info":[
            {
               "Owner":"Jill",
               "Owner_number":"123"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "type":"cat3",
         "name":"Freddy",
         "Colors":[
            "Blue"
         ],
         "Contact_info":[
            {
               "Owner":"Ann",
               "Owner_number":"1323"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```